# Is it possible for async method to ever return null in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task

Digging through some old code, I have noticed a call to an `async`method and then a check for the task being returned for **null**.

```
async Task<Something> DoSomeStuffAsync()
{
    //...
    return null; //not the actual return, but I guess it doesn't matter
}


var result = DoSomeStuffAsync(); //without await
if(result == null)
{
    //does this part makes any sense
}
```

From my understanding of the `async` keyword, this scenario will never be possible because the result of an `async` method will always be wrapped in a `Task` but just to check, am I missing something?

Is there any case when an `async` method will return **null** in C#?

Comment: Have you tested it to find out? If so, what were the results of your test that lead to this question?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds trivial enough that writing a unit test is finger training - you did 90% of the work. literally did spend more time typing this question that it takes to write a test.

Comment: I tested and it does not return null

Comment: the question is not specifically about my case, but should anybody ever check for null an async method?

Comment: `async` is not part of the contract (signature). If the implementor changed the implementation to manage the returned `Task` directly (removed the `async` keyword) and somehow introduced a `null` result, your assumption that it can't return `null` is incorrect. Don't assume that an implementation will use a compiler-generated state machine.

Comment: Maybe this helps to understand why it can't return null - https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlQAs6AsgBQCU1t9AvrzqCGmAByYAbAB5yAPnQAxAPZKu6ALzyAdgFcANnvxI+QA==

Comment: Here without the async keyword - https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwKwG5nJQDMmM6AwugN7Lp2YlQAs6AsgBQCU1t9AvrzqCGmAGwAecgD50AMQD28rugC8MgHYBXADbb8SPkA==

Comment: Having the method `DoSomeStuffAsync` return null is confusing, because this null is unrelated to the question. It is assigned to the `Something`, not to the `Task<Something>`. Hence my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types) async methods can have the following return types:

> - Task, for an async method that returns a value.
> - Task, for an async method that performs an operation but returns no value. void, for an event handler.
> - Starting with C# 7.0, any type that has an accessible GetAwaiter method. The object returned by the GetAwaiter method must implement
>     the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ICriticalNotifyCompletion
>     interface.
> - Starting with C# 8.0, IAsyncEnumerable, for an async method that returns an async stream.

So `Task` represents the execution of the asynchronous method and it should never be `null`,  [because `Task` represents the ongoing process for the caller with a commitment to produce an actual value when the work is complete.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model)

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible for a method marked `async` to return `null`.

However, **for the caller**, a method is not `async` or not, it just returns an awaitable (a `Task`... or other awaitable types, that's out of the scope of the question), so it's indeed possible that it returns `null`.

I.e., the caller can't distinguish between:

```
async Task Foo()
//...
```

and:

```
Task Foo()
//...
```

And the latter method can perfectly return `null`

So a null check is perfectly valid *for the caller*

Comment: you are saying that somebody as a consumer of an `async` method will not know if that method is async or not, but will only know it returns a Task? why is that?

Comment: @meJustAndrew because `async` is not part of the signature... just a syntax-sugar thing (big and complex, but essentially syntax sugar for the compiler to change your code). The compiled IL code doesn't know anything about `async`

Comment: (actually, that's not 100% true... the metadata for an async method information includes some specific attributes so it -could be possible- to know if a method is `async` or not, but let's not get too deep)

Comment: There's no point in going that deep, anyway. Unit testing shouldn't care how the method is implemented, just that it satisfies the contract (to reiterate `async` is not part of that). You *could* look for the attribute and test for null or not based on that, but then you're testing the compiler, not the method.

Answer (score -3):

While it's true that `DoSomeStuffAsync()` could someday be changed into a method that is not `async`, it's pretty clear that it's intended to be `async` and you've probably found a bug. The call was probably meant to be awaited. If the call wasn't meant to be awaited (i.e., `result` was really meant to be a `Task`) then the null check is pointless, and there should probably be a comment explaining why the call wasn't awaited.

Testing for potential future API changes like it becoming possible for `DoSomeStuffAsync()` to return null is not something that belongs in production code. Not trusting API contracts and documentation ("Async" in the method name is a form of documentation) and littering code with pointless null checks is characteristic of inexperienced coders.